# I want to place all names longer than the average length into a new list. This is what I have so far but it prints none

Tags: python-3.x

```
names = ["jeremy","johnathon"]
average = 4

def longestNames(names,average):
  newlist = []
  for i in names:
   if len(names) > average:
    return newlist.append(len(names))

z = longestNames(names,average)
print(z)
```

Ive been trying to figure this out but I either get an error or none. I basically want to place all names longer than average the new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error. the code returns None because both jack and john has a length smaller than average

Edit :
Use this code:

```
names = ["veryyyyyyyy","sml"]
average = 4

def longestNames(names,average):
  newlist = []
  for i in names:
   if len(i) > average:
    newlist.append(i)
  return newlist

z = longestNames(names,average)
print(z)
```

Note list.append() returns None. You have to return the list itself

Comment: even if your change the names it still prints none

Answer (score 0):

The names that you have already selected have the length equal to 4, but you are checking the average bigger than 4. Thus, the returned value would be none. It is better to try other names with the length of 5 or bigger or change the initial average to less than 4.

Comment: Even if the names are bigger than 4 it still prints none